# Responsive grid not working in firefox or opera

Tags: firefox, opera, responsive-design

For some reason my responsive grid is breaking when I open my website in Firefox. I'm using skeleton grid system and I haven't really had any problems with cross browser compatibility before but I modified the grid (to a 8 column grid instead of a 16) and I think I may have broken something.

I can't figure it out because all I did was remove the classes for the other 8 columns.

The columns start where they are supposed to but they are huge and extend off the page now.

Here is the live website: http://nicki.smartbrandidentity.com/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I'd just use the 16 column layout. Use the column2 when you would use a column1. These grids are designed to give you as many options as can fit in a grid, and you shouldn't limit yourself to only 8.

Also, looking at the css, this does not look like a "responsive" grid. All of the columns are set in pixels. If you want a really easy grid that is actually responsive, check out the columnal grid system. http://www.columnal.com/

Comment: The 16 column layout is too wide. I'm very interested in controlling the character count per line on every screen so I wanted a thinner column length. Maybe I should just scrap the skeleton grid and try to find a grid generator for my specific needs?

Comment: you can try the 960 grid system. (http://960.gs/) it has classes for prefixes and suffixes so that you can narrow down your content. by default it it is 960px wide. for example, you could give it a prefix of one column, a width of 10columns and a suffix of 1 column. the documentation explains the concept more thoroughly. make sure you read the docs on these grid systems because most of them have a way of achieving what you are trying to do without editing the actual grid css.

Comment: Hmm... Yeah I think I'll just look into some different grid systems that are more flexible than the one I'm using now. Thanks!